# Excel Table : add blank columns and headers vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table and I want to add a column to it and then name the header. Somehow my old codes don't work anymore, and I am not sure if it has anything to do with me making the data range a table (Name is Table1). Now the codes run through with no error but only add the blank column but did not add a header. I pressed **F8** and it looks like it skips Select portion and jumps to the end.

Table is specified from column A to column AG. I used to be able to insert multiple blank columns and add the headers just fine. Now I don't want to specify cell position and assign a cell value to it (`cell(1, 32).value ="Month"`) since I want to have the flexibility to be add however many columns I need and add the header respectively like before.

```
Sub Ins_Blank_Cols_Add_Headers()
 Columns("AF:AG").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
 Columns("AF:AF").Cells(1, 1) = "<<NewHeader>>"
 Columns("AG:AG").Cells(1, 1) = "<<NewHeader>>"
    Dim cnter As Integer

LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
cnter = 0

For i = 1 To LastCol
  If Cells(1, i) Like "<<NewHeader>>*" Then
        Select Case cnter
            Case 0: Cells(1, i).Value = "Month"
            Case 1: Cells(1, i).Value = "Year"
        End Select
        cnter = cnter + 1
    End If
Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  At this point, you're adding a column at AF (shifting to right and remapping to AG), then labelling the blank column's Row 1.  I ran the code myself and it is doing just that.  Have you checked your references?  I have "Visual Basic for Applications", "Mocrosoft Excel 14.0 Object Library", "OLE Automation", and "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library."  It's at least a start!

Comment: @Cyril, yes all of them are selected in the reference.

Comment: If you guys know a different way around it, please share, I am new to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using `Range.Select` and `Selection`, it will do you good.

---

Also always use fully qualified ranges.

---

Your issue is that when you insert a column in Table, Excel automatically assigns a header name to it.

So your IF condition to check empty fails. Hence No Select case invocation

---

Change this

```
Columns("AF:AF").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

To

```
 Columns("AF:AF").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
 Columns("AF:AF").Cells(1, 1) = "<<NewHeader>>" ' In Table Can't set blank header so use a place holder.
```

Also Change the If Condition from

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(1, I)) Then
```

To

```
 If Cells(1, I) Like "<<NewHeader>>*" Then
```

Comment: Hello, yes, I think that is possibly the case but I just tried and when I insert the blank column it assigns a name for it, Column2. And I just modified my codes, but it's no use.

Comment: Still skipping `Select Case cnter` ?

Comment: Yes, it's still skipping even after your codes assign it to be blank.

Comment: Thank you it works is there a way to modify it so it will work if I insert multiple blank columns?

Comment: it will work with multiple inserts as the If condition is using Like

Comment: I found a way to do it but not sure if there is a more efficient way to do more than 1 column if I am asked to do. I am basically assigning NewHeader to each of the columns I am trying to add.